# Mr-auto in navbar with divs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I would like to split my navbar into left and right navbars. After looking at the bootstrap examples I thought mr-auto is exactly what I would need, however it doesn't work as desired when I use a container **inside** of the navbar. However I want to use the container element inside of the navbar as I am applying a background color for the full width navbar.

**My HTML code:**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-grey navbar-expand-lg">
   <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img class="rounded logo" src="http://www.m2kindia.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/dummy-logo.png"></a><button class="navbar-toggler"></button>
      <div class="d-flex" id="navbar-menu">
         <div class="mr-auto" id="navbar-menu-left-side">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
               <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Home1</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-menu-right-side">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav action-links">
               <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Home2</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bvzvo05d/7/

Edit: Updated JSFiddle, take note that Home2 is a collapsing item, viewport must be enlarged in JSFiddle to see that item.

**Desired result:**

The div showing the Home1 link should be placed on the left and the Home2 div should be right aligned.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that the `d-flex` DIV isn't consuming full width of the `container`. Just use `w-100` to make it 100% width..

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-grey navbar-expand-lg">
   <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img class="rounded logo" src="http://www.m2kindia.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/dummy-logo.png"></a><button class="navbar-toggler"></button>
      <div class="d-flex w-100" id="navbar-menu">
         <div class="mr-auto" id="navbar-menu-left-side">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
               <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Home1</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <div id="navbar-menu-right-side">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav action-links">
               <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Home2</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/ZHFuEAnTcM

Comment: seems like I simplified my example too much. When you apply `class="navbar-collapse collapse"` to the navbar-menu-right-side div it still doesn't work. Any ideas for a clean solution?

Comment: You just want the right side to collapse? Where is the rest of the toggler code.

Comment: Yes exactly, only the right side is supposed to collapse (I've also updated the fiddle). I also added the span tag inside of the toggler button but it doesn't show up for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want like this : [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bvzvo05d/2/)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-grey navbar-expand-lg">


<div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img class="rounded logo" src="http://www.m2kindia.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/dummy-logo.png"></a><button class="navbar-toggler"></button>

      <div class="d-flex" id="navbar-menu" style='width: 50%;'>

         <div class="mr-auto" id="navbar-menu-left-side">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
               <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Home1</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>

         <div id="navbar-menu-right-side">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav action-links">
               <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/">Home2</a></li>
            </ul>
         </div>

      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```